# openmp, linux c not making multiple threads

Tags: c, linux, multithreading, openmp

I have the following code:

```
int main(){
    #pragma omp parallel
    {
    printf("Sample Output");
    }
}
```

This is how I'm compiling it:

```
gcc -o x -fopenmp test.c
```

and this is the result:

```
Sample output
```

But shouldn't the output be something like this?

```
Sample output
Sample output
Sample Output
Sample Output
...
```

I mean shouldn't there be more than one line of output? 1 for each thread?

? One line of output for each thread?

Note: I have a quad core system. I'm running linux on a virtual machine (debian).

Thanks in advance

Comment: Why would there be 4 threads?

Comment: I'm assuming there should be 4 threads since I have a quad core system

Comment: Why would there be 4 threads running your program, and more importantly why would they run every statement once ?

Comment: If you compile it with -g switch and run it in gdb break on printf and execute `info threads` that will show how many threads are created.

Comment: Need more info. Could you post a `main()` containing a minimal verifiable example? What are the values of `omp_get_max_threads()` and `omp_get_dynamic()` just ahead of the parallel section?

Comment: @Eregrith: I don't mean there should be exactly 4. what I'm saying is that there should be more than one output.

Comment: @programming Why? Why would there be even if there were 4 threads? Is there a loop you didn't post? Is there anything letting us know that printf() *should* be executed multiple times?

Comment: @dummydev: I've added the full code. those 2 functions return 1 and 0 respectively.

Comment: @programming: you did call those functions outside of any parallel section, right? Try to set the environment variable `OMP_NUM_THREADS` to `4` **or** call `omp_set_num_threads()` with `4`. What is your program environment? Is it executed directly from the terminal or from another running process? Is the rest of your system seeing the 4 cores?

Comment: @dummydev when I set the omp_set_num_threads() to 4 it works correctly. Though I had initially assumed that the omp call should detect that I have 4 cores on my cpu. As to your other questions, I'm running the program directly from the terminal. To be honest I'm not sure if the rest of the program is seeing the 4 cores or not.

Comment: I was talking about the **system** itself: is the kernel seeing all the cores? About your program, you get 4 threads running when setting the number of threads explicitly but that doesn't mean that your code runs on more than one core. What does `omp_get_num_procs()` return? Behaviour of OpenMP runtimes may be affected by processor affinity: please refer to this [link](http://openmp.org/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=250).

Comment: Try it with optimization: `gcc -o x -O3 -fopenmp test.c`